# callback not calling other methods

Tags: android

I am extending `BluetoothGattCallback` and had to override `onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)`  method to meet the goal of writing to a file.

Inside this method I have a piece of code:

```
try {
    // file already open
    os.write(m.getBytes());
    //doWriteHere(m.getBytes)
}
```

When I run this code the way you see it, it successfully writes to a file. However, I would prefer to use `doWriteHere()` method.

When using the other method, nothing is written even if my method contains only this line: `os.write(values)`.

Is there any reason why this is happening? Is there a way to call the method and make sure it executes the right thing?

EDIT:

```
public class ConnectCallback extends BluetoothGattCallback {

    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
        Log.w(TAG, "Characteristic changed, " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
        try {
            // file already open
            os.write(m.getBytes());
            //doWriteHere(m.getBytes)
        }

    public void doWriteHere(.... {
             os.write(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Method should work fine. Set up some breakpoints and see what actually happens

Comment: Well, I have tested that and it doesn't perform the write as I said...

Comment: Yep, as @cricket_007 says, there's no hidden magic there. Check you pass properly the bytes parameter to the method and it must work the same way the other does.

Comment: You have a try without a catch - what exception are you not printing?

Comment: I have a catch as well... Just skipped it